# Setting up sunspot geolocation scenario

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am using [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) for searching and  using [Geocoder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast) for addresses and then for calculating distances, [Geokit-rails3](https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3).

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  searchable do
    text :name
  end 
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_mappable
  geocoded_by :address, :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lng
  attr_accessible :lat, :lng, :address
  has_many :products
end
```

---

### Question

What I want when typing in a product to search for is also the ability to type an address inside of another field to search for products in that given area with a 30 mile radius.

This is my controller which allows me to search for Products:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = Product.search do |q|
      q.fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
end
```

So I believe the form would look something like this after I am done:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
        <p> Search Near: </p>
        <%= label_tag :location, "Search nearby an Address" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location] %>
<% end %>
```

I am thinking `:location` would serve as a virtual attribute for the Stores `:address` in order for the field to be mapped correctly but this is all speculation.

How do I set this all up in order to achieve the specific scenario?

Comment: Be sure to checkout [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder). I think it exactly answers your question.

Comment: I believe this thread can help you out: https://groups.google.com/group/ruby-sunspot/browse_frm/thread/ecc8231569ea7ef7/f8569abee2197a19?lnk=gst&q=geokit#f8569abee2197a19